# Pandas: How to combine two dataframes by closest index match?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two dataframes `df1, df2` with indexes of the same type, but with few, if any, identical matches. Indexes may also have duplicaes. Columns A and B will consist of internally unique values. All indexes and columns are ordered, but not in the same direction. `df1.index` is descdending and `df1['A']` is ascdending. `df2.index` is ascending and `df2['B']` is descending.

**df1:** (numbers to the left are the unnamed indexes of the dataframes)

```
            A
80 -13.545215
76 -12.270691
73 -11.274724
65  -8.280187
38  -7.965972
13  -7.788130
10  -6.690969
6   -5.273063
```

**df2:**

```
            B
8  -13.827641
10 -12.283885
14 -11.459951
62 -11.067622
64 -10.745988
87 -10.661594
95  -9.816053
97  -7.740810
```

I'd like to combine the dataframes such that the values in `df2['B']` are placed to the nearest corresponding index from `df2` in `df1`, so that the desired output takes the form:

```
            B         A
8  -13.827641 -6.690969
10 -12.283885 -6.690969
14 -11.459951 -7.965972
62 -11.067622 -8.280187
64 -10.745988 -8.280187
87 -10.661594  NaN
95  -9.816053  NaN
97  -7.740810  NaN
```

If the closest index A in absolute terms is lower than index B, then the upper value of index A is the correct match. If index B has no corresponding match in index A that is higher, then NaN is the correct match.

So far, I've used `pd.merge()` and `fillna()` to make necessary analyses. But some may find it "unnatural" to make analyses on interpolated / synthetic data. Anyway, whis is how I've been doing it:

**Partial code sample for `pd.merge()` and `dropna():`**

```
# outer merge
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'outer', left_index = True, right_index = True)
#df4 = df3.interpolate(method = 'linear')[1:]
df4 = df3.interpolate(method = 'linear').dropna()
df4
```

**Output:**

```
            A          B
8   -5.982016 -13.827641
10  -6.690969 -12.283885
13  -7.788130 -11.871918
14  -7.877051 -11.459951
38  -7.965972 -11.263787
62  -8.070710 -11.067622
64  -8.175448 -10.745988
65  -8.280187 -10.729109
73 -11.274724 -10.712230
76 -12.270691 -10.695352
80 -13.545215 -10.678473
87 -13.545215 -10.661594
95 -13.545215  -9.816053
97 -13.545215  -7.740810
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete data and code sample**

```
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df1_index = sorted(np.random.randint(1,101,8), reverse = True)
df1info = {'A':sorted((np.random.normal(10, 2, 8))*-1)}

df2_index = sorted(np.random.randint(1,101,8))
df2info = {'B':sorted(np.random.normal(10, 2, 8)*-1)}

# Two dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1info, index = df1_index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2info, index = df2_index)

# outer merge
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, how = 'outer', left_index = True, right_index = True)

# interpolate missing values
df4 = df3.interpolate(method = 'linear').dropna()

# plot
df4.plot()
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Edit 1: Duplicate scenario 1**:

If `df2.index` has an exact match in `df1.index`, and `df1.index` has a duplicate, then the correct match is the lowest `df1.index`. I hope that makes sense. If it turns out to be nonsensical for some reason, I'm open to other suggestions!

Comment: What happens with the index is duplicated? Should it match to all exact duplicates/nearest duplicates?

Comment: [There's a built-in method for nearest index merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof)

Comment: @G.Anderson `pd.merge_asof` is 1:1, which might not work here because of duplication.

Comment: @ALollz I'm thinking real hard about that right now. Will give feedback ASAP.

Comment: @ALollz forgot about that :/

Comment: @Thanks to everyone taking a look at this. I'm gonna add some edits as well as scenarios for duplicates to make it all a bit more clear. Working on it right now.

Comment: @ALollz I've edited the question with a scenario for duplicates. I hope it makes sense and really appreciate the effort so far!

Comment: @vestland can you give an example for Duplicate scenario 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not "Pythonic" but a `O(n)` solution

```
df2_index.sort()
df1_index.sort()

a = 0
b = 0
mapping = [[],[]]
while b < len(df2_index) and a < len(df1_index):
    if df1_index[a] == df2_index[b]:
        mapping[0].append(df2_index[b])
        mapping[1].append(df1.loc[df1_index[a], "A"]) 
        b += 1
        a += 1
    elif df1_index[a] > df2_index[b]:
        mapping[0].append(df2_index[b])
        mapping[1].append(df1.loc[df1_index[a], "A"])           
        b += 1
    else:
        a += 1

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': mapping[1]}, index = mapping[0])
df2.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Output

```
     B              A
8   -13.827641  -6.690969
10  -12.283885  -6.690969
14  -11.459951  -7.965972
62  -11.067622  -8.280187
64  -10.745988  -8.280187
87  -10.661594  NaN
95  -9.816053   NaN
97  -7.740810   NaN
```

- Both the indices are sorted in ascending order
- `b` points to B's and `a` points to A's index
- At any point of time give a `b` we find the next maximum `a` and save it when we find it
- if `b` == `a` then we are done with those records so we move ahead
- if `a` > `b` then we fond the value of `b` so we move b. We dont move `a` because this can also be a candidate for next `b`
- if `a` < `b` we move `a` because the candidate for `b` will be somewhere after current `a` because it is sorted.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I would also be very interested in other variations of the same setup. Would you mind a follow-up question, or would you rather handle that in a new question?

Comment: @vestland Followup question is fine

Comment: Your suggestion answers my question before the edit. I'm also very curious as to how one would proceed to solve this with columns only and no index. So I believe the fair thing to do is accept your answer as it is, and post a new question with columns only and more properly explained duplicate scenarios.

Comment: sure :) But how will you frame the question without index when your condition of matching is on the index. Also I am eager to see pythonic solution to it.

Comment: I'm struggling with an array of real world variations of the same problem. I may also hva mis-specified this question just a tiny bit to match the exact thing I'm looking for right now =) I only realized that when I started digging even deeper as a response to the requests from Alollz. So a classic case of getting what you ask for, and not what you need... But I'll leave the question open to draw the attention of some pure pythonistas if you prefer....

Comment: Agreed. If you *would* like a follow-up question, how could you have included df1.index.values in the output (as a column)?