# Pandas: How to combine dataframes by related columns with no exact matches, and possible internal duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is related to, but not exactly the same as, [Pandas: How to combine two dataframes by closest index match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365482/pandas-how-to-combine-two-dataframes-by-closest-index-match/55365960?noredirect=1#comment97456267_55365960).

Given two dataframes `df1[['A1', 'B1']]` and `df2[['A2', 'B2']]`, I'd like to combine them so I end up with a dataframe `df3[['A2, 'B2', 'B1', 'A1']]` where alle values of `'A1'` have been matched by the closest `'B2'` to `'B1'`. Below is an example, and you'll find complete data sample and reproducible code at the end.

**df1:** (duplicate B1 = -9.33)

```
       A1     B1
0 -128.65 -12.30
1 -117.74 -11.98
2 -117.19 -11.91
3 -109.43 -10.03
4  -93.75  -9.33
5  -87.27  -9.33
6  -85.59  -5.96
7  -76.18  -5.51
```

**df2:**

```
       A2     B2
0  -69.06 -12.64
1  -86.88 -12.12
2  -95.95 -11.35
3 -103.87 -10.67
4 -105.78  -9.63
5 -108.11  -9.20
6 -111.07  -9.06
7 -126.42  -6.37
```

Pleae note that df2['A2'] is descending while all other columns are ascending.

**Desired output:**

```
       A2     B2     B1   A1
0  -69.06 -12.64 -12.30 -128.65  
1  -86.88 -12.12 -11.98 -117.74  
2  -95.95 -11.35 -10.03 -109.43
3 -103.87 -10.67 -10.03 -109.43 
4 -105.78  -9.63  -9.33 -87.27  
5 -108.11  -9.20  -9.33 -87.27
6 -111.07  -9.06  -5.96 -85.59
7 -126.42  -6.37  -5.96 -85.59
```

**Caveats:**

The correct match for `df2['B2']=-12.12` is `df1['B1']=-11.98` with corresponding `df['A1']=-117.74`, since `df2['B2']=-12.12` is greater than `df2['B2']=-12.30` and `-11.98` is the next step in the column.

For duplicate values `df1['B1'].iloc[4] = df1['B1'].iloc[5] = -9.33`, `df1['A1'] = -87.27` is the correct match since it's the greatest value.

If the best solution includes setting some of the columns as index, I won't mind at all!

**Here's a reproducible snippet:**

```
#imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data
np.random.seed(1234)

data1 = {'A1':sorted(np.random.normal(100, 20, 8)*-1),
         'B1':sorted(np.random.normal(10, 2, 8)*-1)}


data2 = {'A2':sorted(np.random.normal(100, 20, 8)*-1,reverse = True),
         'B2':sorted(np.random.normal(10, 2, 8)*-1)}

# Two dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1).round(2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).round(2)

# Duplicate scenario 1: Duplicate A1 values
df1['B1'].iloc[4] = df1['B1'].iloc[5]
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: should `5 -108.11  -9.20` get merged with `6  -85.59  -5.96`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `pd.merge_asof`, after first dealing with the duplicates. Sort on `'A1'` then drop duplicates on `'B1'`, leaving the greatest value of `'A1'` for each unique `'B1'`:

```
import pandas as pd
#df2 = df2.sort_values('B2') # If not sorted by `B2`

pd.merge_asof(df2, 
              df1.sort_values('A1').drop_duplicates('B1', keep='last').sort_values('B1'),
              left_on='B2', right_on='B1', direction='forward')
```

#### Output:

```
       A2     B2      A1     B1
0  -69.06 -12.64 -128.65 -12.30
1  -86.88 -12.12 -117.74 -11.98
2  -95.95 -11.35 -109.43 -10.03
3 -103.87 -10.67 -109.43 -10.03
4 -105.78  -9.63  -87.27  -9.33
5 -108.11  -9.20  -85.59  -5.96
6 -111.07  -9.06  -85.59  -5.96
7 -126.42  -6.37  -85.59  -5.96
```

---

If you need to keep the original order, consider reseting the index so it's added as a column after the merge, then set it back and sort the index.